# What is apple's preference for connecting ios apps to python code?

Tags: python, ios, swift

I've developed a cool thing in python that does some simple data manipulation and a bit of machine learning stuff based on user inputs. I'd like to develop an ios app for it, and from what I've read, that app should be in swift as much as possible. I'd like to keep the 'brains' of the app in python on a server so I can develop multiple interfaces to it (a website, possibly an android app as well, a chrome/safari extension).

My app could just be a shortcut to the mobile version of the website, but from what I've read, I can make a better product by writing a custom app for ios.

Can anyone point me to resources describing the most apple-approved way of letting a swift app communicate with a server that hosts a python back end?

Comment: Also if this is a huge category of development, then just pointers toward what to google would also be greatly appreciated. All I've come up with so far is people asking how to smuggle python into their app's code, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!
iOS does not make a distinction whether the server runs PHP, Python, Java, JS/Node or whatever. All you need is network communication. The easiest way to start would be to simply use HTTPS (it needs to be SSL secured, if you do HTTP requests Apple will reject your app in review).

Apple gives you some tools directly in Swift. All you need should be covered by `URLSession`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession

There is also a nice tutorial on RayWenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/567-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Additional comment:
This of course means you will need to make sure your Python code is available via Network/Internet. A good way to host Python code as a server would be Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/)